# Datetime in Python, just printing out the time and formatting

Tags: python, time, format

In my program I have:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

And in my program I have:

```
def get_time():
    time = str(datetime.now())
    print("")
    print(time)
    print("")
    return None
```

but it keeps giving me an output of "2013-05-24 08:43:34.727635". I was wondering what I could do to change it to output **just** the time, in a format of "4:36" or "2:30", etc. Like a normal digital clock. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> print datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M')
20:51
```

12-hour

```
>>> print datetime.now().time().strftime('%I:%M %p')
08:53 PM
```